# Convertir un XML que llegar por SOAP PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un WS que me proveé de un XML con información, el problema es que cuando llega, llega como un objeto, tendría que ciclar todo el objeto e ir convirtiendo pieza por pieza, habrá una forma más efectiva de pasar ese objeto a un XML? Al fin y al cabo el documento original es un XML. Necesito guardar en una ruta ese XML y luego presentarlo en una pantalla. No he intentado nada puesto que no se me ha ocurrido nada, únicamente tengo toda la lógica de consumir el WS.

Intenté hacerlo

```
$data = (array) $xml_response; 
//o tambien
$data = json_decode(json_encode($xml_response), true);
```

Esto es un poco lo que regresa, reitero, la respuesta es muy amplia y como podrán notar tiene más objetos dentro (nodos XML)

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["item"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (3) { ["FOO"]=> string(4) "foo_value" ["VAR"]=> string(37) "Var_value" ["POO"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["item"]=> array(8) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (3) { ....
```

Pero no es lo que estoy buscando

Comment: lo que llega es un objeto json o php serializado? podrías dar un ejemplo de la response ( anonimizando los datos ) ?

Comment: Listo ya puse un poco de la respuesta

Comment: es el vardump de data? el response original es un json? fijate https://stackoverflow.com/a/31674872/1423096 si la función te sirve, en https://stackoverflow.com/q/1397036/1423096 hay mas algoritmos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar xml_parse_create, tiene varias opciones para convertir tu XML a un array facil y sencillo. Lo podrias hacer así:

```
$parser = xml_parser_create();  
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_TARGET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_CASE_FOLDING, 0);
xml_parser_set_option($parser, XML_OPTION_SKIP_WHITE, 1); 
xml_parse_into_struct($parser, trim($contents), $xml_values); 
xml_parser_free($parser);
```

y a tus valores

```
$xml_values
```

Podras colocar un foreach, para recorrer tu arreglo y sacar los valores que necesitas o mostrar en pantalla todo tu XML.

Comment: El problema es que el XML es muy grande y tiene varios niveles de profundidad, tendría que hacer varios IF para saber si el elemento actual es un objeto y no una cadena, eso me está llevando bastante trabajo y al final no quedó.

Comment: Puedes hacer uso de **SimpleXMLElement**  o **simplexml_load_file**, puedes encontrar muchos ejemplos de como parsearlo https://diego.com.es/tutorial-de-simplexml